# Need help to compile jnlua with mingw

Tags: c, lua, mingw, jnlua

This problem has stucked me for days.
I have very few knowledge on C, recently I downloaded "jnlua-0.9.6-src.zip" from "https://code.google.com/p/jnlua/downloads/list" and try to compile jnlua.c with following command:

```
mingw32-gcc -m32 -O2 -c -o jnlua.o jnlua.c -Id:\luarock\lua -Id:\java\include\win32 -Id:\java\include
```

As a result, the compiler prints several screens of error messages, below are some of them:

```
jnlua.c:120:1: error: unknown type name 'JNLUA_THREADLOCAL'
 JNLUA_THREADLOCAL JNIEnv *thread_env;
 ^
jnlua.c:120:26: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
 JNLUA_THREADLOCAL JNIEnv *thread_env;
                          ^
jnlua.c:138:1: error: unknown type name 'JNLUA_THREADLOCAL'
 JNLUA_THREADLOCAL jobject newstate_obj;
 ^
jnlua.c:138:27: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'newstate_obj'
 JNLUA_THREADLOCAL jobject newstate_obj;
                           ^
jnlua.c: In function 'newstate_protected':
jnlua.c:148:11: error: 'thread_env' undeclared (first use in this function)
  *ref = (*thread_env)->NewWeakGlobalRef(thread_env, newstate_obj);
           ^
jnlua.c:148:11: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
jnlua.c:148:53: error: 'newstate_obj' undeclared (first use in this function)
  *ref = (*thread_env)->NewWeakGlobalRef(thread_env, newstate_obj);
                                                     ^
jnlua.c: In function 'Java_com_naef_jnlua_LuaState_lua_1newstate':
jnlua.c:31:2: error: 'thread_env' undeclared (first use in this function)
  thread_env = env;\
  ^
jnlua.c:188:2: note: in expansion of macro 'JNLUA_ENV'
  JNLUA_ENV(env);
```

I'm sure that the include paths are correct, no idea why this happens.
Highly appreciated that someone can help, I really need to compile it into dll file because the prebuild dll doesn't support windows XP.

**Update on 22-Mar:**
My problem is finally resolved by following command, thanks for help:

```
gcc -m32 -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -shared -O2 -o jnlua5.1.dll jnlua.c lua5.1.dll -DLUA_WIN -DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL -Id:\luarock\lua -Id:\java\include\win32 -Id:\java\include -static -s
```

Comment: "nmake" inside Visual studio also doesn't work with its makefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your "jnlua/src/main/c/Win32" directory you should find a `Makefile` in there. Though it's initially setup to use Visual Studio's `cl` compiler you can modify it so it works with Mingw.

For example, the following `Makefile` works on my setup:

```
# Makefile.mingw
# Paths
JDK_DIR=G:/jdk
LUA_DIR=G:/Luajit-2.1.0
LUA_INC=$(LUA_DIR)/include/luajit-2.1
VERSION=51

# Tools
CC=gcc
LD=gcc

# Default arguments
CFLAGS=-Wall -pedantic -O0 -DNDEBUG -DLUA_WIN
LDFLAGS=-shared

# Description blocks
all: jnlua$(VERSION).dll javavm.dll

jnlua$(VERSION).dll: jnlua.obj
  $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ -L"$(LUA_DIR)" $^ -l:lua$(VERSION).dll

javavm.dll: javavm.obj
  $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ -L"$(LUA_DIR)" -L"$(JDK_DIR)/lib" $^ -l:lua$(VERSION).dll -l:jvm.lib

jnlua.obj: ..\jnlua.c
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL -I"$(JDK_DIR)/include" -I"$(JDK_DIR)/include/win32" -I"$(LUA_INC)" -c -o $@ $^

javavm.obj: ..\javavm.c ..\javavm.h
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL -DLUA_LIB -I"$(JDK_DIR)/include" -I"$(JDK_DIR)/include/win32" -I"$(LUA_INC)" -c -o $@ $<
```

Then use the following make command:

```
mingw32-make -f Makefile.mingw -C src\main\c\Win32
```

If all goes well this will produce `javavm.obj`, `jnlua.obj` and their corresponding dll output `javavm.dll` and `jnlua51.dll`.

Make sure to change the `JDK_DIR`, `LUA_DIR`, `LUA_INC` and `VERSION` in the makefile as appropriate to fit your setup.

Comment: Thank you, but the jnlua.dll doesn't work. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.lua_version()Ljava/lang/String;
        at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.lua_version(Native Method)
        at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.<clinit>(LuaState.java:116)

Comment: There's also a `jnlua-0.9.6-native.zip` that has the dll's precompiled. Can you see if using those work? Note, you might need the msvcr runtime distiributable since they built it with msvc.

Comment: it doesn't support XP

Answer (score 0):

Judging by [the source](https://code.google.com/p/jnlua/source/browse/trunk/jnlua/src/main/c/jnlua.c?r=129) you probably need to define LUA_WIN.

I don't know much about this particular project, but you could try adding `-DLUA_WIN` to the compiler command.

Really, though, you should go and find some proper installation instructions, because there clearly ought to be some.